# At how many points is this piecewise function discontinuous?

Tags: calculus, functions

> $$f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{3x}{x^2-16}  & \text{when $x\leq 2$} \\[2ex]
> \frac{x-2}{x^2-5x+6} & \text{when $x\gt 2$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> At what points is this piecewise function discontinuous?

My solution:

$x=-4, 4, 2, 3$ are the points  at which the denominator is zero, but $x=4\not\leq2$ and $x=2\not\gt2$. Therefore, the points are $x=-4$ and $x=3$. But the answer is given as $3$.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $f$ is defined at $2.$

Comment: Yes, it is. So does it mean the answer key is wrong?

Comment: The answer key is definitely wrong and the only point of discontinuity is $2.$

Comment: 4 is not out of domain...

Comment: @dmtri. I was misunderstood. Please see edit

Comment: @Dbchatto67 Can you please explain why the only point of discontinuity is 2?

Comment: The function given is not well defined,  as you correct said about the denominators.

Comment: There is still a discontinuity at $2$, and in fact $\lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x)$ exists and is finite (due to some cancellation of zeros). Otherwise you are correct that there is a discontinuity (unrelated to the "piecewise switching") at $-4$ and at $3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about $x=-4$ and $x=3$, but you also need to check $x=2$ since that's the point where you jump from one function to the other.

For the piecewise function to be continuous at $x=2$ you need $$lim_{x \to 2} f(x) = f(2).$$  Since $f(x)$ is defined differently from the left and the right of $x=2$ you will need to instead use each one sided limit.

---

$$lim_{x \to 2^-} f(x) = f(2)$$
$$lim_{x \to 2^-} \frac{3x}{x^2-16} = \frac{3(2)}{(2)^2-16}$$
$$\frac{3(2)}{(2)^2-16} = \frac{3(2)}{(2)^2-16}$$
$$\frac{6}{-12}=\frac{6}{-12}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$

So this one works out.  Now we also need to check the right sided limit.

---

$$lim_{x \to 2^+} f(x) = f(2)$$
$$lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{x-2}{x^2-5x+6} = \frac{3(2)}{(2)^2-16}$$
$$lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{x-2}{(x-2)(x-3)} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{1}{x-3} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{(2)-3} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\frac{1}{-1} = -\frac{1}{2}$$
$$-1=-\frac{1}{2}$$

Clearly this is not true, $-1 \neq -\frac{1}{2}$.  Therefore the two sided limit doesn't exist and so we also have a discontinuity at $x=2$.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 points of discontinuity, see the graph bellow:

[image]

So you are particularly right. But for $x=2$:

\begin{aligned}
\lim_{x \to 2^-}\frac{3x}{x^2-16} &= -\frac 12, 
&&\text{while} \\[2ex]
\lim_{x \to 2^+}\frac{x - 2}{x^2-5x+6} &= \lim_{x \to 2^+} \frac{1}{x-3}=-1,
&&\text{so} \\[4ex] 
\lim_{x \to 2^-}f(x) &\ne \lim_{x \to 2^+}f(x)
\end{aligned}

Comment: It is discontinuous only at $x= 2$ in its domain !! We should check continuity in its domain only